# AWX ec2 inventory multi tags filter

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

Hey guys just finished setting up my awx server, need some help with the instance filter. Is there a way to filter based on multiple tags like on ansible I used the ec2.py and on hosts it was like tag_App_*myapp*:&tag_Env_*staging* is there a way to filter like this on AWX or is there a workaround

ps: I saw the either option but that is not my case, I want both tags on my hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welp actually I found out, for anyone who runs into this, you can simply use the '&' to put together your filter using my case as an example my instance filters end up like this `'tag:App=myapp&tag:Env=staging'`.

ps: you can use the '*', ansible doesn't get lost `'tag:App=*myapp*&tag:Env=*staging*'`